# Conditional expectation with several conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation

Let $ξ_1,ξ_2,...$ be independent identically distributed random variables with finite mathematical expectation, $S_n = ξ_1 + ... + ξ_n, n ∈ \mathbb{N}$. Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the equality $E(ξ_1|S_n,S_{n+1},...) = \frac{S_n}{n}$.
I know that $E(\xi_1|S_n) = \frac{S_n}{n}$, but don't quite understand what to do in case, when we have several conditions $S_n, S_{n+1}, ...$. I would be very grateful for the hint.

Comment: First show the orthogonality condition for sets of the form $S_n,S_{n+l_1},\dots,S_{n+l_k} \in B_1\times\dots\times B_k,k\in \mathbb N$ and the $B_i$ are borel subsets of the real line. I think a standard monotone class should get you the result for $\sigma(S_n,S_{n+1},\dots)$

Comment: Intuitively the same symmetry argument for $E[X_i|S_n]$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ would also hold for $E[X_i|S_n,S_{n+1},...]$. I guess you would formally need to show that conditioning on that full tail $(S_n, S_{n+1},...)$ still does not give you any way to distinguish between $X_1, ..., X_n$.

Comment: @Andrew Zhang I didn't quite understand you. $(S_n, S_{n+1}) = cov(S_n, S_{n+1}) \neq 0$, so they are not orthogonal

Comment: I am thinking of conditional expectation as $L^2$ orthogonal projection, or if you must, its extension to $L^1$. So by orthogonality condition, I mean $E [\varepsilon 1_B] =0$ where $\varepsilon=X-E(X\mid\mathcal F)$ and for all $B\in \mathcal F$

Comment: @AndrewZhang Can we just say $E(\xi_1|S_n, S_{n+1}, ...) = E(\frac{S_n}{n}|S_n, S_{n+1}, ...) = S_n/n$. Equality holds since there is lemma, which says  $E(\xi_i|f(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n)) = E(\xi_j|f(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n))$, where $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is a symmetric function. But we can't use this lemma directly, but i think it's easy to generilize on our example considering $E(\xi_i|f_1(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n), f_2(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n, \xi_{n+1}), ...)$. Maybe such a discussion work?